# My Formula is not dragging with the correct cell values in Excel

Tags: excel, fill, handle

I have a formula in Excel that I am trying to copy and drag down with the fill handle.  Everytime I do though it does not keep the interval of cells correct (8cells).

for Example:

```
=('Other tab name here'!Q785)
=('Other tab name here'!Q793)
=('Other tab name here'!Q801)
```

When I drag down with the fill handle it does not keep the cell interval the same.   All of it is formatted to number and I have also tried with out the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Use INDEX():

```
=INDEX('Other tab name here'!Q:Q,(ROW(1:1)-1) * 8 + 785)
```

Where the `8` is the interval and `785` is the first row desired.

Comment: please post the first formula you used and the next one down that was filled in when dragged down in the comments here.

Comment: ='Other Tab name'!Q9
='Other Tab name'!Q17
='Other Tab name'!Q25






When I drag it down it starts again from:

='Other Tab name'!Q12
='Other Tab name'!Q20
='Other Tab name'!Q28




The formula starts on line 12.

Comment: Those are not my formulas.